# How to use SQL delete using group by and min/max clause

Tags: sql, group-by, where-clause

I have the following sample data as detailed in `Table1`. My requirement is to keep rows where min value of meter which varies 10 to 40 and delete all other records.

With the `Table1` as shown below, I only want to keep where `PMG2_Meter` has a value of 20. For experts it could be very simple.  Appreciate your help. Thanks

I found myself.

```
DELETE
FROM Table1
WHERE SQLIDENTITY NOT IN
      (select g1.SQLIDENTITY
       from Table1 G1
              inner join
            (select PMG2_ORG, PMG2_CATEGORY, min(PMG2_METER) as pmg2_sort
             from Table1
             group by PMG2_ORG, PMG2_CATEGORY) Q1
            on q1.PMG2_ORG = g1.PMG2_ORG
              and q1.PMG2_CATEGORY = g1.PMG2_CATEGORY
              and q1.pmg2_sort = g1.PMG2_METER)
```

[Table-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGkna.png)

[Table-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFai6.png)

[Table-3 (Green to Keep and Red to delete)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBywn.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Copy and paste your data as formatted text here instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM [YourTable] WHERE PMG2_Meter != 20
```

If you find tasks like this one hard I recommend checking some sql tutorials.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The value varies between 10 to 40.  The e.g shows only 20 in other cases 10 might be min value.  We need to use group by clause and keep the min value and delete rest.

Comment: Specify in your question that min value varies. The way you've written it, it seems that you have min value and you have meters that vary between 10 and 40, and that you need to remove all but 20 m. For your question I'd like to know where do you get the min value from? Does it come from a table and how does that table looks?

Comment: Added Table-2 with more data

Comment: The comment down is perfect for what you're asking. I also saw your other comment saying that you need grouping or something which means you need to ask another question, better worded and given all the info so someone can help, because we can't just guess what you need.

Comment: Agree.  This is my first post.  Pardon me.  I have added another picture too to better explain my requirement.  Though I can do it other means.  I sure there will be one SQL can perform.

Comment: The problem isn't the data it's the question. We can't understand what you need. I understood that you need to get rid of all rows that don't have 20 as PMG2_Meter value and I gave you that answer that works. The other person gave you answer that get's rid of the rows that don't have the minimum value which is going to work no matter what value is minimum.

Comment: Appreciate your comment.  If anyone has better solution I will use them otherwise I will code it differently.  Thanks